# Program terminated with Signal 25 , time = 0.06 sec mem =3340KB

Tags: c++, linux

Following code produces run-time error with Signal : 25 when run on ideone.com whereas program runs normally on VS 2013; why is there such a misbehavior??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    int a,b,sqroot,i,j;
    a=1;
    for(i=0;i<=1562500;i++)
    {
        sqroot=sqrt(i);
        for(j=1,b=0;j<=sqroot;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            b++;
        }
        a+=2*b;
        if(sqroot==sqrt(i))
            a--;
        printf("%d,",a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is to print the sum of number of all factors of all digits till the number. Number varies from 0 to 1562500

Comment: your numbers are too big for what that website has allocated for you.

Comment: Presumably it runs for too long, so ideone just kills it.

Comment: Change `int` for `long`.

Comment: The `printf` should print millions of characters on a single line.  I don't see how that runs normally on any system.

Comment: SIGXFSZ - File size limit exceeded. Your code produces too much output for what is allowed on this system.

Comment: @user3386109: It should run normally on almost any system.  Try it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal 25 is (usually) SIGXFSZ, which indicates a quota on individual file size has been exceeded. My guess is that the sandbox in which your program runs has strict limits on output file size and that the output of your program is redirected to a temporary output file. That, along with the fact that you are printing every integer on one line, regardless of whether it passes any of your tests or not, probably leads you to exceed the allowed file size.

Answer (score 0):

The "misbehavior" is explained in the [FAQ - Are there any memory or time constraints for the submitted programs?](http://ideone.com/faq#constraints)

```
Yes, they are as follows:

    compilation time: 10 seconds,
    execution time: 5 seconds (for not logged in users) or 15 seconds (for registered users),
    memory usage: 256 MB.
```

Another reason could be the source itself. If I tag it [c](/questions/tagged/c), but use `iostream` and `using namespace std;`, I get

```
Compilation error   time: 0.02 memory: 2292 signal:25

prog.c:2:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```